# Cauchy's Integral Formula implies Holomorphicity?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Is the converse direction of the Cauchy Integral Formula true? Meaning,

if $f:\mathbb{C}\supseteq U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, and

$$\forall a \in U \space \space f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-a|=R}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz$$

does it mean that f is complex-differenatiable?

Comment: Presumably $U$ is open, and you want this for all $R$ such that the disk of radius $R$ centred at $a$ is contained in $U$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Indeed, I just wanted to minimize clutter

Comment: Also, you mean the *converse* direction, strictly speaking, rather than the inverse direction. I only note it because of the differences of these terms in logic and, as an extension, mathematics.

Comment: Presumably a typo: you want $f(z)$ inside the integral, not $f(a)$, ...

Comment: you have to correct your typo and say what you meant, for example $g(a) = \int_{|z| = r} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} dz$ is analytic on $|a| < r$, this is how we prove that holomorphic $\implies$ analytic

Comment: You are all correct! sorry for the confusion

Comment: @TannerStrunk thanks for correcting me, in my native language we have the same word for both

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No the answer will be only harmonic, as example $f(z)=Re(z)$ the real part of $z$, we know using Cauchy-Riemann equation that a real valued holomorphic function will be constant.

but for all $a=\alpha+i\beta$ 
we have 
$$
\alpha=f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\alpha+R\cos(\theta))d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(a+Re^{i\theta})d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|z-a|=R}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz
$$

but we have another theorem : [morera theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem)  witch say that if a continuous function $f$ on a connected open set $\Omega$ that verify :
$$
\oint_{\gamma} f(z)dz=0 \qquad \forall \gamma \, \textrm{  closed piecewise $C^1$ curve}
$$
then $f$ will be holomorphic.

Answer (score 7):

If you parametrize your integral, you see that your equation is equivalent to

$$ f(a) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(a + r e^{i\theta})\; d\theta$$

and this is true for harmonic functions, not just holomorphic ones.

Answer (score -3):

Well...yes, because then you would have an expression for the nth derivative of f, making f infinitely differentiable/analytic in U and thus holomorphic.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function

Comment: it depends how you correct OP's typo

Comment: Ah ty. Wasn't thinking about the typo.